# When having a C++/CX project, is there a way to set the default Date for a CalendarDatePicker?

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I have a C++/CX UWP project and want the user to pick a Date from the CalendarDatePicker which I created using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls. However, at initialization time I'd like the CalendarDatePicker selcected to a specific date (currently no date is selected and it just says "select a date"). 
I know that this is easily possible with C# and I am quite certain that there is a way with C++ also, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Does anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you look at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.date#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarDatePicker_Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the specific date to the **datePicker->Date**.The complete steps are below.
The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.DateTime) explains the relevant use of DateTime in C++/CX.So we can get DateTime by **SYSTEMTIME->FILETIME->_ULARGE_INTEGER->DateTime**.First,we use **COleDateTime** class to parse specific date string(include **ATLComTime.h** before using) and then convert.

```
#include <ATLComTime.h>

//parse date string
COleDateTime coDT;
coDT.ParseDateTime(L"2012-11-10", 0, 0); 

//get system time struct​
SYSTEMTIME st;​
coDT.GetAsSystemTime(st);​
​
//COleDateTime is in local timezone, DateTime is in UTC, so we need to convert​
SYSTEMTIME st_utc;​
TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(nullptr, &st, &st_utc);​
​
//get filetime struct to get a time format compatible with DateTime​
FILETIME fileTime;​
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st_utc, &ft);​
​
//use _ULARGE_INTEGER to get a int64 to set the DateTime struct to​
_ULARGE_INTEGER ulint = { fileTime.dwLowDateTime, fileTime.dwHighDateTime };​
​
Windows::Foundation::DateTime myDateTime;​
wfdt.UniversalTime = ulint.QuadPart;​

//set date
MyDatePicker->Date = myDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had finally some more time to investigate this.

An easier way to solve this is to use the following code:

```
Windows::Globalization::Calendar calendar;
Myguidatepicker->Date = calendar.GetDateTime();
```